# Convert Date to Text in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to convert date to text format in bigquery. I used below sytax in my query- STRING(DATE(TimeStanmp_1)). please let me know if this is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax you use formally correct, but you don't need to use STRING function here because DATE returns string by itself

So below version should give you the same

DATE(TimeStanmp_1)

Try below to see this:

```
SELECT STRING(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())), DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
```

hover output fields names to see data type